# I have tried almost everything, Python Data Transformation into a range, but keep getting *Int object not callable*

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

I'm trying to transform a column, into a range from 1 to 100, however I keep getting " int object is not callable "

`df['r'] = df['r']. apply (lambda x : (100 - 1)((x-min(df['r']))/((max(df['r'])) - min(df['r'])) + 1`

Returns
`'int' object not callable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a value followed by parentheses denotes a function call.

So, when Python sees this:

```
(100 - 1)((x-min(df['r']))
```

... it simplifies to this:

```
99((x-min(df['r']))
```

... and it thinks you're trying to use `99(...)` as a function call.

In common mathematical notation, `(a)(b)` means "a multiplied by b", but Python doesn't use that notation.  You need an explicit `*` symbol for multiplication:

```
(100 - 1)*((x-min(df['r']))
```